# Errors when attempting to compile AoT in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-aot

When attempting to run "node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json which is the NGC command to compile an AoT application i get these following errors and don't really understand why they're being spit out.

```
$ "node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/app.component.ts:15:11: Parameter 'theme' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/navmenu.component.ts:14:11: Parameter 'theme' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ts:135:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ts:140:32: Parameter 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ts:199:10: Parameter 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ts:204:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ts:241:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ts:39:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ts:93:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ts:47:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ts:122:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ts:156:18: Parameter 'selectedType' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ts:39:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ts:92:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ts:28:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ts:110:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ts:140:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ts:102:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ts:119:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/user.dashboard.component.ts:71:64: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/user.dashboard.component.ts:71:67: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/save.dashboard.component.ts:134:23: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:191:43: Property 'newDashboard' is private and only accessible within class 'AdminDashboardComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:319:40: Property 'selectedDash' does not exist on type 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:323:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:323:55: Property 'selectedDash' does not exist on type 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:358:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:358:55: Property 'selectedDash' does not exist on type 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/admin.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:389:32: Property 'selectedDash' does not exist on type 'NewDashboardDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:628:43: Property 'pressAddFields' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardGeneralComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:693:43: Property 'pressAddStatic' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardGeneralComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:943:40: Property 'newFieldName' does not exist on type 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:947:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:947:55: Property 'newFieldName' does not exist on type 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:1007:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:1007:59: Property 'newFieldName' does not exist on type 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.general.ngfactory.ts:1038:32: Property 'newFieldName' does not exist on type 'AddDashFieldDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ngfactory.ts:134:43: Property 'pressAdd' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardCustomComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ngfactory.ts:150:43: Property 'pressDelete' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardCustomComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ngfactory.ts:679:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddCustomDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.custom.ngfactory.ts:718:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddCustomDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:178:43: Property 'pressAdd' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardDynamicComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:194:43: Property 'pressDelete' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardDynamicComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:405:43: Property 'pressEditProperties' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardDynamicComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:611:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddDynamicDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:648:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddDynamicDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:845:40: Property 'newEndpoint' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:954:40: Property 'newUsername' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1031:44: Property 'newPassword' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1152:64: Property 'newDashName' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1152:80: Property 'newDashType' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1177:64: Property 'newDashName' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1177:80: Property 'newDashType' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1207:36: Property 'newEndpoint' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1215:36: Property 'newUsername' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.dynamic.ngfactory.ts:1219:36: Property 'newPassword' does not exist on type 'AddEditRestDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:139:43: Property 'pressAdd' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardMessageComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:155:43: Property 'pressDelete' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardMessageComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:645:44: Property 'newMessageName' does not exist on type 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:649:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:649:59: Property 'newMessageName' does not exist on type 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:684:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:684:55: Property 'newMessageName' does not exist on type 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.message.ngfactory.ts:715:32: Property 'newMessageName' does not exist on type 'AddMessageDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:137:43: Property 'pressAddAdmin' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardSecurityComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:153:43: Property 'pressDeleteAdmin' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardSecurityComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:207:43: Property 'pressAddUser' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardSecurityComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:223:43: Property 'pressDeleteUser' is private and only accessible within class 'EditDashboardSecurityComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:346:44: Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:350:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:350:59: Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:387:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:387:55: Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:420:32: Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:438:32: Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:548:44: Property 'newUser' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:552:43: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:552:59: Property 'newUser' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:589:39: Property 'pressSubmit' is private and only accessible within class 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:589:55: Property 'newUser' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:622:32: Property 'newUser' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/edit.dashboard.security.ngfactory.ts:640:32: Property 'newUser' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationTwoDialog'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/save.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:37:39: Property 'pressSave' is private and only accessible within class 'SaveDashboardComponent'.
Error at C:/Users/DTurcich/Source/Repos/Interns/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/aot/src/app/save.dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts:57:43: Property 'pressCancel' is private and only accessible within class 'SaveDashboardComponent'.
```

Pertinent files for AoT

tsconfig-aot.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "../../node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },

    "files": [
        "src/app/app.module.ts",
        "src/main.ts"
    ],

    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "aot",
        "skipMetadataEmit": true
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'; 
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

console.log('Running AOT compiled');
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

I want to migrate from JIT to AOT for faster load times and so that when I implement Tree Shaking it's more effective, but i don't know what to do about these errors. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the app with `ng run --prod` will do the tree-shaking and run the app using **AOT** compilation.

If you're interested in more details i found their **wiki** quite useful.

#### [ng-cli Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling--tree-shaking)

Oh and you can of course use `ng build --prod` as well.

---

Regarding the errors I suggest you start using [TS Lint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) because you're breaking some typescript rules, mostly regarding using private properties outside the class they were declared in and implicit type definitions (not declaring the type, yes even **any** type).
I highly recommend using JetBrains **PHPStorm** or **WebStorm** as your editor they provide a bunch of amazing tools and it's very easy to enable TS Lint inspections in them.
*They are not free though.*

Comment: I'll look into this, I didn't know that Angular 4 had built in AOT and Tree-Shaking that's awesome! Also I'm using Visual Studio Professional atm.

Comment: Yeah I've spent a lot of time trying to get my app "prepared" for AOT I've even fixed **ALL** of the errors typescript was not happy with. And then once i was at the bottom of the pit I've found out Angular4 supports AOT out of the box when you use `--prod` (which they failed to mention in their documentation at the time). I don't have much experience with VS but I have some colleagues who work in it and from what I've seen it lacked a lot of features JetBrains provide. But hey if you're interested look into it. I will warn you they are pretty **heavy-duty** editors.

Answer (score 2):

- For all the `Parameter '***' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

In your **tsconfig-aot.json**, you ask for `noImplicitAny`.

So Typescript tells you when you declare a variable without specifying a type.

- For all the `Property '***' is private and only accessible within class '***'.`

It's because you have template html that try to access private component property. Without AOT compilation, it doesn't complain about it, because it's JS, but with AOT, it's Typescript, so the privacy is checked.

- For all the `Property '***' does not exist on type '***'.`

It's the same, you access some properties in your templates that doesn't exist for Typescript. Maybe you did some magic allowed in JS, but Typescript is much more strict.

Comment: Think about checking this answer if it resolves your issue